# OpenUI5 with Spring Boot Web - can these work together?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, sapui5

I'm trying to create a very simple Spring Boot 1.3.3 Web application with Thymeleaf and embedded Tomcat using OpenUI5 as the client-side javascript UI library... **but I can't seem to get OpenUI5 to load the data-sap-ui-resourceroots. Is this supposed to be possible?**

I started by going to [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) and generating a maven project with Web and Thymeleaf dependencies and then added in a basic OpenUI5 structure with an XML view. I followed the following tutorials:

1. [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)
2. [OpenUI5 Walkthrough - Step 4: XML Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064.html)

I ended up with the following project structure:

```
root
├── src
│    ├── main
│    │    ├── java
│    │    │   └── myPackage
│    │    │       ├── controllers
│    │    │       │   └── LandingPageController.java
│    │    │       └── Application.java
│    │    └── resources
│    │        ├── application.properties
│    │        ├── static
│    │        │   └── webapp
│    │        │       └── view
│    │        │           └── App.view.xml
│    │        └── templates
│    │            └── landingPage.html
│    └── test
│        └── java
│            └── myPackage
│                └── ApplicationTests.java
│
└── pom.xml
```

Even though it's all basically standard from those tutorials, for completeness, I'll include my source code:

Application.java:

```
package myPackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

LandingPageController.java:

```
package myPackage.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LandingPageController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirect() {
        return "landingPage";
    }
}
```

landingPage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SAPUI5 Walkthrough</title>
    <script
     id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
     src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
     data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
     data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
     data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
     data-sap-ui-preload="async" 
     data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"
     }'>
    </script>
    <script>
     sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
         sap.ui.xmlview({
             viewName : "sap.ui.demo.wt.view.App"
          }).placeAt("content");
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
  </body>
</html>
```

App.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <Text text="Hello World"/>
</mvc:View>
```

My application.properties file is empty and the pom.xml is exactly what was generated by the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

I believe the issue is with this line in the landingPage.html, but I don't know what else to put other than "./":

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"
     }
```

I was able to get this to work up to step 3 in the OpenUI5 tutorial; however, it seems that once I have to define the view in an XML file, the OpenUI5 library cannot locate it. I don't know where else to put the App.view.xml file, I would have thought that anywhere under the static folder would be fine...

I'm not sure if this has to do with the fact that I'm using an embedded Tomcat, but I'd like this to work using embedded Tomcat.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: What does the URL to your landingPage.html look like?

Comment: The way that I understand Spring MVC to work, you can't actually find landingPage.html via URL since it is actually a view template and not a static resource. Based on the RequestMapping defined in the LandingPageController, by navigating to http://localhost:8080/ it will trigger the redirect() method which will render the landingPage.html view template. The only static file I have is the OpenUI5 XML view which can be found at http://localhost:8080/webapp/view/App.view.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Spring or any of the mentioned Java frameworks, but I can try to help you with the resourceRoots.

With that setting, you can tell the OpenUI5 framework, where to find certain resources.

A setting of `"sap.ui.demo.wt": "./"` means that everything starting with `sap.ui.demo.wt` can be found in the same directory as the current page / file. Any further `.<something>` means a subfolder with that name.

You can define the resourceRoots relative to your html file or absolute by using for example:
`"sap.ui.demo.wt": "/resources/static/webapp"`
In that case your view with the name `sap.ui.demo.wt.view.App` will be found (or at least looked for) at `/resources/static/webapp/view/App.view.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist @hirse. When I run the app, as it stands, I can find the view at http://localhost:8080/webapp/view/App.view.xml. So in the resourceRoots, I tried to set it to `"sap.ui.demo.wt": "/webapp"` and I even tried `"sap.ui.demo.wt": "/webapp/view"`. I also took your suggestion and tried `"sap.ui.demo.wt": "/resources/static/webapp"`. None of these work... I'm not sure how it is using resourceRoots to search the server, but I'm wondering if embedded Tomcat is hindering this in some way...

Comment: Alternatively (and less ideal) is there a way to specify resources explicitly instead of allowing them to be found by defining a root? Something like `sap.ui.registerResource("/webapp/view/App.view.xml")`?

Comment: @sadiq, you can use the browsers developer tools to see which path is requested and try to adapt accordingly.